# How can I find the most recent tag in a branch following a commit?

Tags: git

Given a branch, and a commit, how can I find the closest tag **following** that commit in the branch? Or, how can I find the first tag after a given date following that commit in the branch?

Comment: Programmatically? If not, have you fired up `gitk`? (Or, in Eclipse, the "History" view?)

Comment: What about `git tag --contains [$HEAD]`? It shows the tags that contain $HEAD. It shows them all, I guess, not just the first one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try and use [`git describe`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-describe):

```
git describe --contains <commit>:
```

> Instead of finding the tag that predates the commit, find the tag that comes *after* the commit, and thus contains it.
>   Automatically implies `--tags`.